# Join unallocated space with GParted

Tags: partitioning, gparted, join, unallocated

I need to join a 96.47GB partition with 155GB partition with "GParted", without modify `/dev/sda1`.

How can I do it? D: See screenshot of GParted window [here](http://droppy.com.ar/kazuki/shared-cloud/04-03-2012%20%2811:40:41%29.png)
Sorry for my poor english, I'm japanese xD

Comment: Geirha's answer is perfect. Please just note that within gparted, to move the inner swap partition you must first enlarge the outer partition, then move the inner partition to the right, and finally shrink to the previous size. After that, you can then increase the size of your main partition (ex: sda).

Answer (score 3):

You move all partitions to the left. You have to do this from a live session, since you can't move the filesystem underneath your currently booted system's feet.

So.

- boot the Ubuntu CD
- open gparted (the live session has it preinstalled)
- unmount any partitions that may be mounted (indicated by the key icons), the swap partition is likely used by the live session, so this must be unmounted.
- resize the extended partition (/dev/sda1) to cover the entire drive
- drag and move the other two partitions to the left.

Moving partitions like that may take a few hours.